# Java Set not adding object when selecting items from Listbox

Tags: java, zk, jooq

I am using **Java**, **Jooq** and **Zk7** for my application but i am getting one issue see my scenario 
I have **Listbox** which showing all the records in model i Have a add button when click on it i am adding new element in **Listbox** something like this

```
    private ListModelList<Record> adminListModelListSort;
    protected ListModelList<Record> adminListModelList;

    ValidWorkRecord new_record1 =  new ValidWorkRecord();
    adminListModelList.add(new_record1);
    adminNewListModelList.add(new_record1);
```

Listbox adding item no any issue but when i am taking back selected item i am getting single record
And select item is something like this

```
WorkCode|WorkDesc|StatCanWorkType|StampDate|StampUser|AccessCode|WorkDesc2|Comments|ActiveFlag|
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------+---------+--------+----------+
| *{null}|*{null} |*{null}        |*{null}  |*{null}  |   *{null}|*{null}  |*{null} |*{null}   |
```

So i added 5 new items in the **Listbox** and its showing 5 item added but when i am trying to get selecteditem it show only 1 item added if i am making any change in newly added item then it showing that item as a selected .
Note:-first time newly added item content null values only .
Do you know what is the issue with java **Set**

```
private Set  selectedListItem;//get,set method
```

But when i tried below code everything worked fine
ZUL Page

```
    <?page title="new page title" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
 <window title="new page title" border="normal" id="inp"
  viewModel="@id('vm') @init('test.MyListbox')" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"  >
  <button label="AddItem" onClick="@command('addNewItem')"  ></button>


  <listbox model="@bind(vm.dataList)" selectedItems="@bind(vm.selectitems)" multiple="true" checkmark="true">
   <listhead>
    <listheader value="A"></listheader>
    <listheader value="B"></listheader>
    <listheader value="C"></listheader>

   </listhead>
   <template name="model" var="mymodel">
    <listitem>
     <listcell>

      <textbox value="@bind(mymodel.a)" />
     </listcell>
     <listcell>
      <label value="@bind(mymodel.b)" />

     </listcell>
     <listcell>
      <label value="@bind(mymodel.c)" />

     </listcell>
    </listitem>
   </template>
  </listbox>
 </window>
</zk>
```

View Model Code

```
package test;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.AfterCompose;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextType;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.NotifyChange;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;

public class MyListbox {

 private List<Data> dataList;
 private Set selectitems;

 @AfterCompose
 public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
  try {
   dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
   Data data;
   data = new Data("a1", "b1", "c1");
   dataList.add(data);
   data = new Data("a2", "b2", "c2");
   dataList.add(data);
   data = new Data("a3", "b3", "c3");
   dataList.add(data);
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
 }



 public Set getSelectitems() {
    return selectitems;
}



public void setSelectitems(Set selectitems) {
    this.selectitems = selectitems;
}



@Command
 @NotifyChange("dataList")
 public void addNewItem(){
  Data data = new Data(null, null, null);
  dataList.add(data);
  if(selectitems != null)
  System.out.println(selectitems.size());
 }
 public List<Data> getDataList() {
  return dataList;
 }

 public void setDataList(List<Data> dataList) {
  this.dataList = dataList;
 }

 public class Data {
  String a;
  String b;
  String c;
  public String getA() {
   return a;
  }
  public String getB() {
   return b;
  }
  public String getC() {
   return c;
  }
  public void setA(String a) {
   this.a = a;
  }
  public void setB(String b) {
   this.b = b;
  }
  public void setC(String c) {
   this.c = c;
  }
  public Data(String a, String b, String c) {
   super();
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   this.c = c;
  }

 }
}
```

Why Set behaving two way in two places?

Comment: What types did you put into Set? If two objects are equals (`e1.equals(e2)`) then set will treat them as duplicates and won't add it into the collection

Comment: can you provide zul listbox code.

Comment: *its showing 5 item added* -- How did you check that? Does the `selectedListItem.add(...)` statement return `true`?

Comment: With the class Data everythings works normal or do you have also problems there? If Data works normal, what is your equals and hashcode from ValidWorkRecord?

Answer (score 2):

[A `Set` cannot contain duplicates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), but a List can. 2 objects `o1` and `o2` are considered duplicates if `o1.equals(o2)` returns true (or both are `null`). If you try to add a duplicate, it will be ignored (`add()` will return false).

If you always add your items this way:

```
ValidWorkRecord new_record1 =  new ValidWorkRecord();
selectedListItem.add(new_record1);
```

then there is a chance that they are considered equal, depending on your `equals()` method.

Indeed, calling the constructor without other modifications will initialize all your items the same way. If you overrode `equals()` so that it is not based on the pointer value anymore, then you should check the return value of `add(...)` to be sure your items are added.

---

**UPDATE**: You don't seem to control the `add(...)` statement as far as I understand, so you can't check for its return value. But, now that I see your data class, you haven't overriden `equals()` so this shouldn't be the problem.

However, you probably **shouldn't use the raw type** `Set`, but `Set<Data>` instead.

Also, try and put a trace in your setter `setSelectitems()` to check if the method is at least called.

Comment: items are added in Listbox and available in ZK page but selected item show only single item even i added 5 items which are visible

Comment: @askkuber Do you actually select multiple items? I'm not familiar with ZK, but you should probably check what type the `selectedItems` attribute is supposed to be bound to.

Comment: Yes i am using  selectedItems="@bind(vm.adminListboxViewModel.selectedListItem)" and mutiple="true" checkbox="true"

Comment: @askkuber I meant, do you select them **in your UI**? I think `selectedItems` is there for the items **selected by the user** in the UI, not all the added items in the list.

Comment: Yes selecteditem come when checkbox wil be checked i am doing same .If i am adding new items and not making any change it count selected item is1 but when i am making any small change it count that item as a diffrent itemd then showing in selected item set

Comment: @askkuber Then it's because the items are considered duplicates. Have you tried with a list instead of a set?

Comment: i edited my quetion added a code which is working fine but another case its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use List for selectedListItems instead of Set. Listbox works fine with 5 new items because Listitem objects are placed in a List. So they can be duplicated by 5 list item. But there is only one data object add to the selected set. Hope this help.